# CSS Box Explanation - inner margin and outer container border affecting height

Tags: html, css

I can't get my head around this but with the basic div containing an inner div if you remove the border style from either of the div element then the height of the overall box is affected?!? 
Can someone explain this for me please?

```
<div style="background-color:red;border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="margin:10px;background-color:blue;border:1px solid black;">
        <p style="margin:30px;background-color:gray;border:1px solid black;">test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you guys simulate this? does the height change if you remove the border styles?
Hope someone can shed some light on this
Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The height (and width) is determined by the total of the css width, height (or width), margin and padding. It's call The CSS Box Model and W3Schools has a detailed [explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp).

Comment: It's not totally correct. Padding (not margin) does affect "visible" width. Margin affects, well, margins. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/images/boxdim.png. Element width is: width + left/right padding + left/right border. Everything "after" border is not entirely element width.

Comment: On second thought, technically speaking margin is specified on the element and w3schools are somehow right on calculating width. But my teaching experiense tells me that this wording usually misguides people. It comes from the fact that margin is transparent and does not include visible content.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a border it adds whatever number of pixels you specify to the outside of the element, so in that sense it will change the height of your element.

It will then affect the height of the div that it is in if it does not have a fixed height.

Hope this helps some.